# Finding a name using bs4 from <td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Metaverse ETP">

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

First I know very little about html which I think is my problem. I am having trouble finding a specific coin name in my search. I am not sure whether to find the name using the td label it has or maybe there is a better way.

Before picking this back up I would search a specific part but when updates would come around it would move the names and prices around so it was definitely not ideal but worked during that time. I went back into it trying to find a way to look for the name of the coin rather than where it is placed.

```
def loadPageCM():
     # Grabbing url with requests
     page = requests.get('https://www.coinmarketcap.com')

     # Sending page to Bs4 to parse info
     soup = bs4(page.text, 'html.parser')

     divs = soup.findAll('table', id='currencies')

     content = []
     # finds all div tags and loops through them
     for div in divs:
         rows = div.findAll('tr')
         for row in rows:
         # looping through all the row in the singular div
         # appending to content array and removing the ending portion
         content.append(row.text.replace('\n', '')[:-115])
```

This is the original code I used. I am sorry I am extremely new.

What I am trying to do is now find these coins based on their names. from this tag.

td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="COIN"

If there is a better way then i'm fine with any advise. Again apologizes if the question does not make any sense or any improvements with asking on here or my code in general is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Since you know the attributes of the tags that you want, get them from `soup.find_all()` using the tag's [attrs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

**TL;DR**:

```
# Grabbing url with requests
page = requests.get('https://www.coinmarketcap.com')

# Sending page to Bs4 to parse info
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tds = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'no-wrap currency-name'})

for td in tds:
    print(td['data-sort'])   # change to get whichever attributes you want
```

Explanation:
`soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'no-wrap currency-name'})` will return all 100 names (rows) from the page.

Then for each `td` (row) we access the attribute we want. For example, on the first row, `<td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Bitcoin">`, `td.attrs` shows all available attributes: `{'class': ['no-wrap', 'currency-name'], 'data-sort': 'Bitcoin'}`. So to get only the coin's name attribute, use `td['data-sort']` to get the name `Bitcoin`.

If you want to get more information from the rows, like `Market Cap`, `Price`, or `Volume` do the same technique for the other `td`s: `<td class="no-wrap market-cap text-right"`, and use dictionary-like access to those attributes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much for your time and reply this is a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to target a specific coin by `data-sort` value e.g. `Bitcoin`

```
soup.select_one("[data-sort='Bitcoin']")
```

And say you wanted to isolate that row, so as to get all its associated values: with bs4 4.7.1. you can use `:has` to isolate the row having the above data-sort

```
row = soup.select_one("tr:has([data-sort='Bitcoin'])")
```

Example of last part when looking at specific coin values

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
row = soup.select_one("tr:has([data-sort='Bitcoin'])")
print([re.sub(r'\n+' , ' ' ,item.text.strip()) for item in row.select('td')])
```

Comment: Ah I see,  thank you very much for your time and reply.